# Opening a screen out the result of a statement

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-navigation

enter code hereI want to open a screen to add extra information if it is not set yet. So after the user is logged in I check if the extra info is set. If not I want it to go to a screen to fill in the info. If the user is done it should go to a "Homescreen". If the user info is already set it should immediately go to the home screen.

I already tried to just go to the extra info form and then `Navigator.push` to the home screen but then it has difficulties with logging out. I searched for a long time but can not find anything.

```
class CampPage extends StatelessWidget {
final String email;
final String uid;
const CampPage({super.key, required this.email, required       this.uid});

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return FutureBuilder(
    // ignore: unrelated_type_equality_checks
    future: context.read<UserProvider>().exists(uid) == true
        ? null
        : Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => NewUserPage(email:  email, userId: uid),
              ),
            );
          }),
    builder: (context, snapshot) => Scaffold(
      drawer: const DrawerHomePage(),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Camp Page"),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: const [
          Text("nieuwe features"),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

}

this is one of the things I try but the NewUserPage always pops up and I only want it to pop up if `context.read<UserProvider>().exists(uid) == false`

also the solution mentioned does not work for me. I think because there is a screen in between the login and logout (The form screen) the logout function does not work properly.
`
class UserPage extends StatelessWidget {
const UserPage({super.key});

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ElevatedButton(
        child: const Text("Submit"), 
        onPressed: () {
          //Log out of Firestore Authentication
        },
        ),
    );
  }
}

  class NewForm extends StatelessWidget {
  const NewForm({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ElevatedButton(
        child: const Text("Submit"), 
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => const UserPage()),
                  );
        },
        ),
    );
  }
}


  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return FutureBuilder(
    future: context.read<UserProvider>().exists(uid)
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasdata){
                if (snapshot.data == true) {
                  return const UserPage();
                } else {
                  return const NewForm();
                }
           }
          else // show a proggress bar
   } 
  
  );
}
```

`

Does someone still have another solution?

Comment: can you provide some code or images of what you want, more detail.

Comment: Just added some more code. Hope it clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do this:

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return FutureBuilder(
    future: context.read<UserProvider>().exists(uid)
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasdata){
                if (snapshot.data == true) // then the user exist
                else // the user doesn't exist
           }
          else // show a proggress bar
   } 
      
  );
}
```

Comment: This does not work unfortunately because this way firebase Authentication will work properly. I added some code at the top to explain this more. Do you know another solution?